# Java Scanner for peeking something (int, double, line, etc) without advancing position

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

We know that `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `nextLine()`, etc methods of Java `Scanner` class *parses* something (int, double, line, etc) and *advances* the position of the scanner. But I need a way only for *parsing* something but not for *advancing* the position. That means, I need some way for something like `peekInt()`, `peekDouble()`, `peekLine()`, etc methods.

Here is an example for why it may be necessary. Suppose, I have an abstract class `Server` which has an abstract method `respond(Scanner in, PrintWriter out, String clientIp)` to be implemented by other classes. Here is the portion of code:

```
public abstract class Server {
    // ... (some initialization variables)

    public static final String endSocketMarker = "END";

    public final void runServer() {
        // ... (multithreading code)

        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        String clientIp = in.nextLine();
        String marker = "";
        do {
            respond(in, out, clientIp); // call abstract method
            marker = in.nextLine(); //TODO: find a way so that input line is peeked (but not skipped)
        } while(!marker.equals(endSocketMarker));

        // ... (close client socket)
    }

    protected abstract void respond(Scanner in, PrintWriter out, String clientIp);

    // ... (other methods)
}
```

Here `marker = in.nextLine();` *parses* the line until a line separator found and then *advances* the position to the beginning of the next line. If `marker.equals(endSocketMarker)` is false, then the string assigned in `marker` cannot be read inside `respond(in, out, clientIp)` method at all. It must be avoided somehow. I may pass the variable `marker` into `respond(in, out, clientIp)`, but it will make the code cluttered.

Is there any better way for achieving my goal?

Comment: Same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: @parsecer: The API does not provide anything for that. I had to handle that manually as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Scanner.hasNext()` method Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

There's an example here,
[hasNext() example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm)

Comment: `hasNext()` method returns true if the scanner has another token in its input but it does not return the token. But I need that token *without advancing the position of the scanner*. I think, I could not explain my question to you.

Comment: The scanner doesn't advance past that token, it stays there.

Comment: All the methods containing `next` (for example `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `nextLine()`) advance the position of the scanner, otherwise always same string would be returned for consecitive method calls. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) is a line 'The position is set to the beginning of the next line.' It is similar for the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking for the next token via a `Pattern` with the corresponding [`hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext-java.util.regex.Pattern-). This way you are not advancing the position, but you are able to peek the next token (via its pattern)...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        final String endSocketMarker = "END";
        final String testString = "This is some test text.\n1234567890\n" + endSocketMarker + "\nThis is still writing...";
        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(testString.getBytes(charset)), charset.name());
        final Pattern endPattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(endSocketMarker));
        while (!scan.hasNext(endPattern))
            System.out.println("Processing input, with first line being: \"" + scan.nextLine() + "\".");
        System.out.println("Reached the \"" + scan.nextLine() + "\".");
    }
}
```

The point of converting the `testString` to an `InputStream` which is supplied to the `Scanner` exists just to demonstrate how to use an `InputStream` with the `Scanner`. Otherwise I could just simply supply the `testString` directly to the `Scanner`'s constructor.

---

I was thinking also about supplying the `Scanner` with a `BufferedInputStream` and using `mark`/`reset` on the latter, but after some tests and a bit of searching, I found out that `Scanner` internally uses a buffer. Which means that the `Scanner`'s buffer is getting filled with all the data from the `BufferedInputStream`, thus advancing the position of the `BufferedInputStream` without letting us mark the proper location. Even if you create a new `Scanner` object every time, using the same `BufferedInputStream` will have the same effect, as the `BufferedInputStream` will be advanced anyway.